Photo Reduction Tool version 2 - Possible reinvention of the wheel
The code is a Linux command line photo size reduction tools. It reduces the size of all the photos in a directory. It may work on Windows 10, but it has not been built or tested on Windows. It takes about 2.3 seconds to resize 20 photos. 116 photos were resized and renamed in 11.2 seconds.
This is my first use of the OpenCV library  and Boost program_options.
This is a complete rewrite of the code in my previous question. The differences between this version and the previous version:

While objects defined by the OpenCV library and Boost program_options library are used, all the code in the question is procedural rather than object-oriented. This change is based on comments from the previous version of the code.
This version contains command-line processing.
This version finds all the photos in the specified directory.
The user has the option of replacing the current photos with the resized photos.
The user has several different ways of specifying the new size of the photos.

Motivation for Program

I have about 200 photos that I need to up load to a WordPress website. When I tried up loading the second one I got an error message that the file was too wide. Apparently WordPress limits the width of the photo uploads to 2560 columns (pixels?).
I converted 32 by hand and then got tired of all the manual labor.

Most of the questions I ask on Code Review are learning projects as well as demonstrations of code I can write. In this case I wanted to start learning the OpenCV library and the Boost program_options library. My goal was to write as little code as possible to get the job done.
A second goal is to keep my C++ coding skills current so I try to use the most modern features of C++ I can. In this case I am using the C++ file system library introduced in C++17, and ranges and views introduced in C++20. If there are any features from C++23 that will reduce the amount of code written or improve the code in some other way please let me know.
One of the things that I find most satisfying as a software engineer is that I am always learning new things on almost every project.
Things I've learned so far in this project:

It is much easier to use boost program options than to write my own command line parser.
The boost program options allows shorter version of switches then intended, for instance --web-safe works instead of web-safe-name. I am not sure I am comfortable with this; the wrong switch might get used.

Development Environment

C++23
GCC 12
Boost 187
opencv 4.10
Ubuntu 22.04
Cmake 3.31
Visual Studio Code

What to Check For
The valgrind program tells me I have memory leaks, so I would appreciate any help finding them.
Since the code is procedural, rather than object-oriented, is there any coupling between the different parts of the program, and if there is, how can it be reduced?
Are there any header files in the code that aren't used and should not be there?
Is there any way to make this more user-friendly than it already is?
Is the code maintainable?
Is this C++ or is it really C?
The Code
The code as presented here is available in a GitHub Repository. It include a CMakeLists.txt file for building using CMake.
fileCtrlValues.h
#ifndef FILE_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H
#define FILE_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

#include <string>

struct FileCtrlValues
{
    bool fixFileName = false;
    bool processJPGFiles = true;
    bool processPNGFiles = false;
    std::string sourceDirectory;
    std::string imageTargetDirectory;
    std::string imageProcessedDirectory;
    std::string resizedPostfix;
};

#endif // FILE_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

photoCtrlValues.h
#ifndef PHOTO_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H
#define PHOTO_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

#include <string>

struct PhotCtrlValues
{
    bool displayImage = false;
    bool maintainRatio = false;
    std::size_t maxWdith = 0;
    std::size_t minWidth = 0;
    std::size_t maxHeight = 0;
    std::size_t minHeight = 0;
    unsigned int reductionToPercentage = 0;
};

#endif // PHOTO_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

Executionctrlvalues.h
#ifndef EXECUTION_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H
#define EXECUTION_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

/*
 * Storage for environment and commandline argument variables. These structures
 * contain most of the information to execute the program after the command 
 * line has been processed.
 * 
 * The list of photo files is separate.
 */
#include "fileCtrlValues.h"
#include "photoCtrlValues.h"
#include <string>

struct ExecutionCtrlValues
{
    std::string progName;
    bool enableExecutionTime = false;
    FileCtrlValues fCtrlV;
    PhotCtrlValues pCtrlV;
};

#endif // EXECUTION_CONTROL_VARIABLES_H

PhotoFileList.h
#ifndef PHOTOFILELIST_H_
#define PHOTOFILELIST_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct PhotoFile
{
    std::string inputName;
    std::string outputName;
};

using PhotoFileList = std::vector<PhotoFile>;

#endif // PHOTOFILELIST_H_

UtilityTimer.h
#ifndef CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H
#define CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H

/*
 * Encapsulates execution timing for all or parts of a program.
 */

#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

class UtilityTimer
{
public:
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    void startTimer() noexcept
    {
        start = clock::now();
    }
    void stopTimerAndReport(std::string_view whatIsBeingTimed) noexcept
    {
        clock::time_point end = clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        double ElapsedTimeForOutPut = elapsed_seconds.count();

        using std::chrono::system_clock;
        auto const now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
        std::clog << "finished " << whatIsBeingTimed << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%c")
              << "\nelapsed time in seconds: " << ElapsedTimeForOutPut << "\n\n\n";
    }

private:
    clock::time_point start = clock::now();
};

#endif // CC_UTILITY_TIMER_H

CommandLineParser.h
#ifndef COMMAND_LINE_PARSER_H
#define COMMAND_LINE_PARSER_H

#include "Executionctrlvalues.h"

bool processCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[], ExecutionCtrlValues& executionCtrl);

#endif // COMMAND_LINE_PARSER_H

CommandLineParser.cpp
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include "CommandLineParser.h"
#include "Executionctrlvalues.h"
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

static std::string simplify_name(char *path)
{
    return std::filesystem::path{path ? path : "PhotoResizeTool"}.filename().string();
}

namespace po = boost::program_options;

static po::options_description addOptions()
{
    po::options_description options("Options and arguments");
    options.add_options()
        ("help", "Show this help message")
        ("max-width", po::value<std::size_t>(), "The maximum width of the resized photo")
        ("max-height", po::value<std::size_t>(), "The maximum height of the resized photo")
        ("maintain-ratio", "Maintain the current ratio of width to height")
        ("percentage", po::value<unsigned int>(), "The new size of the photo as a percentage of the old size")
        ("source-dir", po::value<std::string>(), "Where to find the original photos")
        ("save-dir", po::value<std::string>(), "Where to save the resized photos")
        ("extend-filename", po::value<std::string>(), "Add the specified string to the resized photo")
        ("web-safe-name", "Change all non alpha numeric characters in filename to underscore")
        ("only-jpg", "Only process the JPEG format photos (default)")
        ("only-png", "Only process the PNG format photos")
        ("jpg-and-png", "Process both the JPEG and PNG format photos")
        ("display-resized", "Show the resized photo")
        ("time-resize", "Time the resizing of the photos")
    ;

    return options;
}

static bool fileExtensionErrorCheck(po::variables_map& inputOptions)
{
    bool noUserError = true;

    if (inputOptions.count("only-jpg") && (inputOptions.count("jpg-and-png") || inputOptions.count("only-png")))
    {
        noUserError = false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("jpg-and-png") && (inputOptions.count("only-jpg") || inputOptions.count("only-png")))
    {
        noUserError = false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("only-png") && (inputOptions.count("only-jpg") || inputOptions.count("jpg-and-png")))
    {
        noUserError = false;
    }

    if (!noUserError)
    {
        std::cerr << "use only one of --only-jpg, --only-png or --jpg-and-png.\n";
    }

    return noUserError;
}

static void setExtensionValues(po::variables_map& inputOptions, FileCtrlValues& fileCtrl)
{
    // Provide a default of JPG files.
    if (inputOptions.count("only-jpg") ||
        (!inputOptions.count("only-jpg") && !inputOptions.count("only-png") &&
        !inputOptions.count("jpg-and-png"))) {
        fileCtrl.processJPGFiles = true;
        fileCtrl.processPNGFiles = false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("only-png")) {
        fileCtrl.processJPGFiles = false;
        fileCtrl.processPNGFiles = true;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("jpg-and-png")) {
        fileCtrl.processJPGFiles = true;
        fileCtrl.processPNGFiles = true;
    }
}

static bool convertInputToFileCtrlValues(po::variables_map& inputOptions, FileCtrlValues& fileCtrl)
{
    if (!fileExtensionErrorCheck(inputOptions))
    {
        return false;
    }

    setExtensionValues(inputOptions, fileCtrl);

    if (inputOptions.count("save-dir")) {
        fileCtrl.imageTargetDirectory = inputOptions["save-dir"].as<std::string>();
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("source-dir")) {
        fileCtrl.sourceDirectory = inputOptions["source-dir"].as<std::string>();
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("extend-filename")) {
        fileCtrl.resizedPostfix = inputOptions["extend-filename"].as<std::string>();
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("web-safe-name")) {
        fileCtrl.fixFileName = true;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool maintainRatioCheck(po::variables_map& inputOptions, PhotCtrlValues& photoCtrl)
{
    if (inputOptions.count("maintain-ratio")) {
        if (inputOptions.count("max-height") && inputOptions.count("max-width"))
        {
            std::cerr << "Only one of --max-width or --max-height can be specified with maintain-ratio\n";
            return false;
        }

        if (!inputOptions.count("max-height") && !inputOptions.count("max-width"))
        {
            std::cerr << "A maximum size, either width or height must be specified with maintain-ratio\n";
            return false;
        }

        photoCtrl.maintainRatio = true;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool photoSizeRequirements(po::variables_map& inputOptions, PhotCtrlValues& photoCtrl)
{
    if (!maintainRatioCheck(inputOptions, photoCtrl))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!inputOptions.count("max-height") && !inputOptions.count("max-width") &&
        !inputOptions.count("percentage"))
    {
        std::cerr << "A new size must be specified using --percentage, --max-width or --max-height\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("max-width"))
    {
        photoCtrl.maxWdith = inputOptions["max-width"].as<std::size_t>();
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("max-height"))
    {
        photoCtrl.maxHeight = inputOptions["max-height"].as<std::size_t>();
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("percentage"))
    {
        photoCtrl.reductionToPercentage = inputOptions["percentage"].as<unsigned int>();
    }

    return true;
}

static bool convertInputToPhotoCtrlValues(po::variables_map& inputOptions, PhotCtrlValues& photoCtrl)
{

    if (!photoSizeRequirements(inputOptions, photoCtrl))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("display-resized"))
    {
        photoCtrl.displayImage = true;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool covertInputToExecutable(po::variables_map& inputOptions, ExecutionCtrlValues& executionCtrl)
{
    if (!convertInputToPhotoCtrlValues(inputOptions, executionCtrl.pCtrlV))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!convertInputToFileCtrlValues(inputOptions, executionCtrl.fCtrlV))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (inputOptions.count("time-resize")) {
        executionCtrl.enableExecutionTime = true;
    }

    return true;
}

static const int MinArgCount = 2;
static std::string usageStr =
    " :\n\tReduce the size of all the photos in the specified folder.\n"
    "\tIf no source location is specifed the photos must be in the current folder.\n"
    "\tA reduction size value must be specified, either by maximum width, maixmum\n"
    "\theight or a percentage of the current size.\n"
;

bool processCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[], ExecutionCtrlValues& executionCtrl)
{
    executionCtrl.progName = simplify_name(argv[0]);

    po::options_description options = addOptions();

    po::variables_map optionMemory;        
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options), optionMemory);
    po::notify(optionMemory);    

    if (argc < MinArgCount)
    {
        std::cout << executionCtrl.progName << usageStr << "\n";
        std::cout << options << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (optionMemory.count("help")) {
        std::cout << options << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (!covertInputToExecutable(optionMemory, executionCtrl))
    {
        std::cout << executionCtrl.progName << usageStr << "\n";
        std::cout << options << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

photofilefinder.h
#ifndef PHOTOFILEFINDER_H_
#define PHOTOFILEFINDER_H_

#include "fileCtrlValues.h"
#include "PhotoFileList.h"

PhotoFileList buildPhotoInputAndOutputList(FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues);

#endif // PHOTOFILEFINDER_H_

photofilefinder.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include "fileCtrlValues.h"
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include "photofilefinder.h"
#include "PhotoFileList.h"
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

// std::filesystem can make lines very long.
namespace fsys = std::filesystem;

using DirectoryMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, fsys::path>;

static void findDirectory(std::string target, std::string errString, 
     fsys::path defaultDir, std::string dirIndex, DirectoryMap& dirMap
)
{
    fsys::path foundDir  = defaultDir;

    if (!target.empty())
    {
        foundDir = fsys::current_path();
        foundDir.append(target);
        if (!fsys::exists(foundDir))
        {
            std::cerr << "The " << errString << " directory " << target << 
                " can't be found!\n";
            foundDir.clear();
        }
    }

    dirMap.insert({dirIndex, foundDir});
}

static DirectoryMap findAllDirectories(FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues)
{
    DirectoryMap dirMap;

    findDirectory(ctrlValues.sourceDirectory, "photo source", fsys::current_path(), "SourceDir", dirMap);
    fsys::path defaultDir = dirMap.find("SourceDir")->second;

    findDirectory(ctrlValues.imageTargetDirectory, "photo target", defaultDir, "TargetDir", dirMap);
    findDirectory(ctrlValues.imageProcessedDirectory, "photo target", defaultDir, "RelocDir", dirMap);

    return dirMap;
}

static void addFilesToListByExtension(std::filesystem::path cwd, std::string extLC, 
        std::string extUC, std::vector<std::string>& photoList)
{
    auto is_match = [extLC, extUC](auto f) {
        return f.path().extension().string() == extLC ||
            f.path().extension().string() == extUC;
    };

    auto files = fsys::directory_iterator{ cwd }
        | std::views::filter([](auto& f) { return f.is_regular_file(); })
        | std::views::filter(is_match)
        | std::views::transform([](auto& f) { return f.path().string(); });

    std::ranges::copy(files, std::back_inserter(photoList));
}

static std::vector<std::string> findAllPhotos(fsys::path originsDir, FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tempFileList;

    if (ctrlValues.processJPGFiles)
    {
        addFilesToListByExtension(originsDir, ".jpg", ".JPG", tempFileList);
    }

    if (ctrlValues.processPNGFiles)
    {
        addFilesToListByExtension(originsDir, ".png", ".PNG", tempFileList);
    }

    return tempFileList;
}

static std::string changeNonAlphaNumCharsToUnderscore(std::string inName)
{
    std::string webSafeName;

    auto toUnderScore = [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::isalnum(c)? c : '_'; };

    std::ranges::transform(inName, std::back_inserter(webSafeName), toUnderScore);

    return webSafeName;
}

static std::string makeOutputFileName(
    std::string inputFileName,
    fsys::path targetDir,
    FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues
)
{
    fsys::path outNameBasis = inputFileName;
    std::string ext = outNameBasis.extension().string();
    std::string outputFileName = outNameBasis.stem().string();

    if (ctrlValues.fixFileName)
    {
        outputFileName = changeNonAlphaNumCharsToUnderscore(outputFileName);
    }

    if (!ctrlValues.resizedPostfix.empty())
    {
        outputFileName += "." + ctrlValues.resizedPostfix;
    }

    outputFileName += ext;

    fsys::path targetFile = targetDir;
    targetFile.append(outputFileName);

    if (fsys::exists(targetFile))
    {
        std::cerr << "Do you want to replace the photo: " << targetFile.string() << "?\n(y | n)>>\n";
        std::string response;
        std::cin >> response;
        if (response == "n")
        {
            targetFile.clear();
        }
    }

    return targetFile.string();
}

static void copyInFilesToPhotoListAddOutFileSpec(
    FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues,
    std::vector<std::string>& inFileList,
    PhotoFileList& photoFileList,
    fsys::path targetDir
)
{
    for (auto file: inFileList)
    {
        PhotoFile currentPhoto;
        currentPhoto.inputName = file;
        currentPhoto.outputName = makeOutputFileName(file, targetDir, ctrlValues);
        if (currentPhoto.outputName.empty())
        {
            // If there was a replacement that the user replied no to, do they want to quit?
            std::cerr << "Do you want to quit?(y / n)\n";
            std::string response;
            std::cin >> response;
            if (response == "y")
            {
                photoFileList.clear();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            photoFileList.push_back(currentPhoto);
        }
    }
}

PhotoFileList buildPhotoInputAndOutputList(FileCtrlValues& ctrlValues)
{
    PhotoFileList photoFileList;
    DirectoryMap directories = findAllDirectories(ctrlValues);

    for (auto& directory: directories)
    {
        if (directory.second.empty())
        {
            return photoFileList;
        }
    }

    fsys::path sourceDir = directories.find("SourceDir")->second;;

    std::vector<std::string> inputPhotoList = findAllPhotos(sourceDir, ctrlValues);
    
    if (inputPhotoList.size())
    {
        fsys::path targetDir = directories.find("TargetDir")->second;
        copyInFilesToPhotoListAddOutFileSpec(ctrlValues, inputPhotoList, photoFileList, targetDir);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "No photos found to resize!\n";
    }

    return photoFileList;
}

PhotoResizer.h
#ifndef PHOTORESIZER_H
#define PHOTORESIZER_H

#include "photoCtrlValues.h"
#include "PhotoFileList.h"

std::size_t resizeAllPhotosInList(PhotCtrlValues& ctrlValues, PhotoFileList& photoList);

#endif

PhotoResizer.cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "photoCtrlValues.h"
#include "PhotoFileList.h"
#include "PhotoResizer.h"

static cv::Mat resizePhoto(cv::Mat image, std::size_t newWdith, std::size_t newHeight)
{
    cv::Size newSize(newWdith, newHeight);

    cv::Mat resizedImage;

    cv::resize(image, resizedImage, newSize);

    return resizedImage;
}

static cv::Mat resizePhotoByWidthMaintainGeometry(cv::Mat image, std::size_t maxWdith)
{
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(image.cols)  <= maxWdith)
    {
        return image;
    }

    double ratio = static_cast<double>(maxWdith) / static_cast<double>(image.cols);
    std::size_t newHeight = static_cast<int>(image.rows * ratio);

    return resizePhoto(image, maxWdith, newHeight);
}

static cv::Mat resizePhotoByHeightMaintainGeometry(cv::Mat image, std::size_t maxHeight)
{
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(image.rows)  <= maxHeight)
    {
        return image;
    }

    double ratio = static_cast<double>(maxHeight) / static_cast<double>(image.rows);
    std::size_t newWidth = static_cast<int>(image.cols * ratio);

    return resizePhoto(image, newWidth, maxHeight);
}

static cv::Mat resizePhotoByPercentage(cv::Mat image, unsigned int percentage)
{
    double percentMult = static_cast<double>(percentage)/100.0;

// Retain the current photo geometry.
    std::size_t newWidth = static_cast<int>(image.rows * percentMult);
    std::size_t newHeight = static_cast<int>(image.cols * percentMult);

    return resizePhoto(image, newWidth, newHeight);
}

static bool saveResizedPhoto(cv::Mat resizedPhoto, std::string webSafeName)
{

    bool saved = cv::imwrite(webSafeName, resizedPhoto);

    if (!saved) {
        std::cerr << "Could not write image " << webSafeName << " to file!\n";
    }

    return saved;
}

static cv::Mat resizeByUserSpecification(cv::Mat image, PhotCtrlValues ctrlValues)
{
    if (ctrlValues.maxWdith > 0 && ctrlValues.maxHeight > 0)
    {
        return resizePhoto(image, ctrlValues.maxWdith, ctrlValues.maxHeight);
    }

    if (ctrlValues.reductionToPercentage > 0)
    {
        return resizePhotoByPercentage(image, ctrlValues.reductionToPercentage);
    }

    if (ctrlValues.maintainRatio)
    {
        if (ctrlValues.maxWdith > 0)
        {
            return resizePhotoByWidthMaintainGeometry(image, ctrlValues.maxWdith);
        }
        if (ctrlValues.maxHeight > 0)
        {
            return resizePhotoByHeightMaintainGeometry(image, ctrlValues.maxHeight);
        }
        std::cerr << "Neither width nor height were specified with"
            " --maintain-ratio, can't resize photo!\n";
        return image;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ctrlValues.maxWdith > 0 && ctrlValues.maxHeight == 0)
        {
            return resizePhotoByWidthMaintainGeometry(image, ctrlValues.maxWdith);
        }
        if (ctrlValues.maxHeight > 0 && ctrlValues.maxWdith == 0)
        {
            return resizePhotoByHeightMaintainGeometry(image, ctrlValues.maxHeight);
        }
    }

    return image;
}

static bool resizeAndSavePhoto(PhotoFile imageName, PhotCtrlValues ctrlValues)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imageName.inputName);
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read image " << imageName.inputName << "!\n";
        return false;
    }

    cv::Mat resized = resizeByUserSpecification(image, ctrlValues);

    if (ctrlValues.displayImage)
    {
        cv::imshow("Resized Image", resized);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return saveResizedPhoto(resized, imageName.outputName);
}

std::size_t resizeAllPhotosInList(PhotCtrlValues& ctrlValues, PhotoFileList& photoList)
{
    std::size_t resizedCount = 0;

    for (auto picture: photoList)
    {
        if (resizeAndSavePhoto(picture, ctrlValues))
        {
            ++resizedCount;
        }
    }

    return resizedCount;
}

main.cpp
#include "CommandLineParser.h"
#include "Executionctrlvalues.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PhotoFileList.h"
#include "photofilefinder.h"
#include "PhotoResizer.h"
#include "UtilityTimer.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int executionStatus = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    std::locale::global(std::locale{""});
    std::clog.imbue(std::locale{});

    try
    {
        ExecutionCtrlValues executionCtrl;

        if (processCommandLine(argc, argv, executionCtrl))
        {
            PhotoFileList photoFiles = buildPhotoInputAndOutputList(executionCtrl.fCtrlV);

            if (photoFiles.size() > 0)
            {
                UtilityTimer stopWatch;

                if (resizeAllPhotosInList(executionCtrl.pCtrlV, photoFiles) != photoFiles.size())
                {
                    std::cerr << "Not all photos were resized\n";
                    executionStatus = EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                std::string report(std::to_string(photoFiles.size()) + " photos resized\n");

                if (executionCtrl.enableExecutionTime)
                {
                    stopWatch.stopTimerAndReport(report);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << report;
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return executionStatus;
}


Valgrind should give you a pretty good idea of where your leaked memory came from, assuming you compile with debugging information (e.g. gcc -g).

@TobySpeight One of the problems was I wasn't calling cv::Mat:release() to release the photo, still looking for other leaks.

Inconsistent header guard. Two end with extra underscore XX_H_ while most end XX_H.

“The boost program options allows shorter version of switches then intended, for instance --web-safe works instead of web-safe-name. I am not sure I am comfortable with this; the wrong switch might get used.” This can be disabled by setting (disabling) a style flag: allow_guessing. It’s been a while, but I seem to recall that it is on by default because it won’t mismatch—the wrong switch can never get used—so it is safe to leave it as is.

Just checked to confirm my memory. --web-safe is unambiguously --web-safe. --web-safe-n (or even just --web-safe-) is unambiguously --web-safe-name. --web-saf fails with an ambiguous_option exception, which shows the potential matches.

@LokiAstari I meant for all of the to have the extra underscore. Good catch!

@indi The link to the style flag is very helpful!

Be consistent
You are not very consistent with how you name things. Here is a non-exhaustive list of inconsistencies:

FileCtrlValues: you use the abbreviation Ctrl here, but the header guard has the unabbreviated word CONTROL in it.
Values: the header guard uses the word VARIABLES.
fileCtrlValues.h: starts with a lower case letter and capitalizes subsequent words, but Executionctrlvalues.h starts with an upper case letter and doesn't capitalize subsequent words.
PhotCtrlValues: missing an o.
fCtrlV: heavily abbreviated, but the type is FileCtrlValues.
simplify_name(): snake_case while most other function names are camelCase.
Photo: in other places you use the word image.

More general, pick one code style and stick to it, and if you abbreviate something, use that abbreviation consistently or not at all.
Also, if reasonable, try to be consistent with the wider C++ world. In particular, I would rename fsys to fs, since that's what's used on cppreference.com (see this example).
Naming things
There's some room for improvement when it comes to naming things. For example:

Photo: the word is associated with real-life images taken by a camera. However, your program works on images in general, whether those are photos, drawings, textures, AI-generated images, and so on. I would rename this to Image where possible.
CtrlValues: I think a better name is Options.
reductionToPercentage: I would rather rename this scaleFactor. I would also avoid storing a literal percentage, but rather a float between 0 and 1.
ExecutionCtrlValues: since this stores the result of processCommandLine, why not write CommandLineOptions? ProgramOptions would also be fine I think.
PhotoFile: this is neither a photo nor a file. It just stores two filenames. Maybe FilenamePair? But perhaps it should go entirely:
PhotoFileList: again it doesn't contain photos or files, it's just a list of filenames. That you use it to store filenames of photos or images is irrelevant for the type. That you put the word photo or image in a variable of that type is fine though.
UtilityTimer: sure this is a utility, but almost everything is a utility. Just name it Timer.
fileExtensionErrorCheck(): function names should be verbs to describe their action, or sometimes describe the return value if they don't have any side-effects. So checkFileExtensions() would be an option, or perhaps better areFileExtensionValid().
convertInputToFileCtrlValues(): instead of Input, I would use CommandLineOptions. And instead of convert, a more common term for this is parse or process. Since parsing is already done by Boost here, and we only process a subset of the options related to filenames and such, I'd recommend processFileOptions().
covertInputToExecutable(): that really sounds like you are creating an executable. Maybe processOptions()?
findDirectory(): this doesn't find directories, it just adds them to a map (with some error checking).
changeNonAlphaNumCharsToUnderscore(): sure that is what this function is doing at a low level, but the goal here is to make the filename web safe. So makeWebSafe() might be better.
copyInFilesToPhotoListAddOutFileSpec(): this function name is too confusing. Does it copy files or just filenames? What does Spec even mean here?

Remove fluff
Avoid adding frills and fluff that are not really needed to your program. Why measure the time it takes to resize all images? External tools can do that for you (on Unix, there's the standard time command). Why show the images after resizing? External image viewers, and even most file browsers can do this for you, and likely much better.
Even making filenames web-safe is something that's probably best left to an external tool, especially since someones idea of web-safe might be different than yours; after all, dots and dashes are also web-safe, and depending on the context, even more characters might be fine for the user.
These unnecessary features take time and effort to implement, are a potential source of bugs, and often give the user a suboptimal experience.
Consider removing PhotoFileList
Why generate a list with all input and output filenames up front? You could easily rewrite your program to generate these on the fly. Instead of:
PhotoFileList photoFiles = buildPhotoInputAndOutputList(options);
resizeAllPhotosInList(options, photoFiles);

You can write:
processFiles(options, resizeImage);

Where resizeImage() is a function that processFiles() calls for each filename it finds. Or, since you tagged this question with c++23, consider writing a generator, so you can write:
for (auto filename: generateInputFilenames(options)) {
    resizeImage(options, filename);
}

Don't make an empty list a special case
There was no need to check for photoFiles.size() > 0, the code works fine without it. In fact, by making this a special case, your program now no longer prints anything when the list of input images is empty. I'd rather see the message "0 photos resized".
Avoid using out parameters
Avoid using out parameters, and instead just return values where possible. For example, convertInputToFileCtrlValues() should instead look like:
static FileOptions processFileOptions(const po::variables_map& inputOptions) {
    FileOptions fileOptions;
    …
    if (inputOptions.count("save-dir")) {
        fileOptions.targetDirectory = inputOptions["save-dir"].as<std::string>();
    }
    …
    return fileOptions;
}

Of course, here you also want to be able to return an error. I recommend just using exceptions here, and write something like:
if (!areFileExtensionsValid(inputOptions)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid combination of file extension flags");
}

Or since C++23 you can use std::expected to wrap the return value.
Make it work like other command line utilities
Typically, command line utilities that process files take a list of filenames on the command line. This is much more flexible than having a --source-dir and some flags to select between JPG and PNG files. The user can just write a glob pattern which the shell will already expand for you, or they can use tools like find to generate a list of files based on whatever criteria they have.
I would keep the output directory a command line option. What would be helpful would be to add a --recursive option, so that if directories are specified on the command line, your code will recurse into those using std::filesystem::directory_iterator.
Remove the options to select between JPG and PNG. I'm sure OpenCV can handle many more file types than those, so it will only make your program more useful.
Since the goal is clearly to do batch resizing, I would also make your program not ask any questions, but skip input files that would cause the output to overwrite an existing file, unless either a flag has been set to overwrite unconditionally (--overwrite), or to enable user interation (--interactive).

My case may be special, the fluff of renaming the file was mandatory for me. I have 158 file with the name BHHS Class of 74 50th Reunion Individuals (###).jpg. That is how the vendor provided them. ### being a number between 1 and 164.

Why not create a separate tool to make filenames web-safe?

One argument against the glob pattern thing is that UNIX tools don't work when directories have too many files. *.png could expand to something that exceeds the character limit for a command. But I do agree that following conventions is usually best, and taking a list of file names as input is a lot more flexible.

I obviously have some very bad naming habits I need to fix.

Regarding the memory leak: I don't see anything you do that should lead to a memory leak. cv::Mat should not leak if you don't call release(). It does reference counting, when a variable goes out of scope the reference count is decreased (just like release() does), and when the count gets to 0 the memory is freed. If you don't use naked new or std::malloc() you generally don't need to worry about memory leaks in your C++ program. But it is entirely possible that OpenCV has a bug and leaks memory.
CommandLineParser.cpp
std::filesystem::path implicitly converts to std::string, so you don't need to call .filename().string() in simplify_name().
The three options "only-jpg", "only-png" and "jpg-and-png" lead to complicated logic to figure out what the user wants. I would just have two options: process-jpg and process-png. If one is set, then it processes images of that type.
In fileExtensionErrorCheck() you see some of the difficulties with these three options, and then in setExtensionValues() you again have to do all these checks. And then internally you set the booleans fileCtrl.processJPGFiles and fileCtrl.processPNGFiles, which is a much simpler logic that should extend to the user interface.
In fileExtensionErrorCheck(), noUserError is a difficult variable name, because if (!noUserError) doesn't read easily. You could name this correctUsage, or invert the logic and start with userError = false, then check if (userError).
usageStr has two typos: "specifed" and "maixmum". Your IDE should be highlighting these (mine did, though it also highlighted "\theight" as a typo...).
CommandLineParser.h
Executionctrlvalues.h, fileCtrlValues.h and photoCtrlValues.h all define a single struct. I don't see the value in keeping separate files for each. I would probably have a single include file for this whole project, declaring all the structs and functions that need to be globally accessible. I could see having separate include files for a large project where independent components each have one include file. But I don't think the current program has any independent components (except for UtilityTimer.h, which is clearly it's own, reusable thing).
I did say in your previous version of this program that I disliked the concept of a class representing the whole program. But I don't dislike classes in general, sometimes they are useful. I like your current structure, but I wouldn't have a negative reaction to ExecutionCtrlValues being a class with a constructor that takes (int argc, char* argv[]) as inputs.
photofilefinder.cpp
My IDE is warning on many input arguments to the functions here:

Clang-Tidy: The parameter 'target' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference.

So for example, you should declare:
static void findDirectory(std::string const& target, std::string const& errString, 
     fsys::path const& defaultDir, std::string const& dirIndex, DirectoryMap& dirMap

This is true in other files too. When passing objects, always consider how expensive it is copy. A very short std::string just needs to copy a few bytes. A longer string (also the case if you don't know if your string will be longer or shorter than the short string optimization of your compiler allows) needs to allocate memory and copy over the string. The memory allocation is expensive. And it is unnecessary. Passing the value by const reference means there's no copy, and the function cannot modify the value.
A struct like struct vector{ double x; double y;} should not be passed by reference, because copying it is not expensive and it'll be cheaper to access the values inside the function (when passing by reference you end up with an indirection, passing by reference is like passing a pointer to the object). Large objects, objects that manage data on the heap, or objects that manage some other resource, should always be passed by reference (either const if input or non-const if the function needs to modify it).
Edit: I realize that some languages like C# always pass objects by reference. In C++ you need to be explicit about how you pass something. type var is by value (makes a copy), type& var is by reference, and type const& var is by const reference. Always do the latter unless you have a reason to pick one of the others. There’s also type&& var, but you don’t generally need that other than in a move constructor and move assignment.
Similarly, in
for (auto file: inFileList)

you are copying each of the elements of the list. Instead, do
for (auto const& file: inFileList)

PhotoResizer.cpp
The same applies here to cv::Mat, pass them by const reference into functions (in your repo you already changed this). Copying a cv::Mat doesn't involve allocation and copying pixel data, but it does involve incrementing and decrementing the reference counter, and copying all of the information in the object itself (which contains quite a lot of member variables related to how to interpret the pixel data pointed to).
The resized images look bad. Especially so if scaling down by a large amount. This is because there is aliasing when resampling an image (or any signal) at a lower sampling rate without a low-pass filter. The documentation to cv::resize say:

To shrink an image, it will generally look best with INTER_AREA interpolation

This interpolation method applies a (poor) low-pass filter that should avoid most of the aliasing artifacts. Thus:
cv::resize(image, resizedImage, newSize, 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);

Better results can be obtained by using a better low-pass filter. But most of the time this is good enough.
Note also that you don’t need to explicitly create the newSize object in this function. You can write
cv::resize(image, resizedImage, {newWdith, newHeight}, 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);

The curly braces will implicitly call the constructor for cv::Size.
